# Tinymce textarea do not work while initializing using javascript

Tags: tinymce

I'm having a problem trying to use tinymce for my textarea. My textarea is kept hidden on pageload using javascript. I've used the following code to initialize tinymce & show it upon clicking a button.

```
$('#buttonID').click(function(){
    $('#textareaID').show();
    $('#textareaID').tinymce({
        //Settings here 
    });
});
```

Upon clicking the button, the tinymce editor shows up for a fraction of sec after which the textarea falls back to the plain textarea.

The other solution I tried is to initialize tinymce using the following code & hide the textarea on pageload. Clicking a button can successfully show it but the input area is inactive & I can't enter any text. The same text area works perfectly fine if I don't hide it on pageload.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
    //settings here
});
</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i advise most people to use the non-jquery tinymce build, the jquery build leads to various problems and is slow